# Safari is frozen once I share the link to my app from share extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

My app implements `Share` extension. I can share any link to my app from Safari, once I tap `POST` button within `SLComposeServiceViewController` share view disappear, but screen of Safari is frozen. I need to force close Safari to use it again.

- **What may be the reason of this?**
- **How can I prevent from happen this in the future?**

This is how my `didSelectPost()` looks like:

```
override func didSelectPost() {
    AddToWishlistNetworkClient.sharedClient().createItemForWishlistIdentifier(selectedWishlist!.identifier, addressOrUrl: composePropertyUrlSheet.value, comment: contentText, completionBlock: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you do everything within `didSelectPost()` the `completeRequestReturningItems:` method **MUST** be called, so that the host app can un-block its UI.

```
AddToWishlistNetworkClient.sharedClient().createItemForWishlistIdentifier(selectedWishlist!.identifier, addressOrUrl: composePropertyUrlSheet.value, comment: contentText, completionBlock: { error in

    self.extensionContext?.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the previous answer, at the end of your didSelectPost() make sure to call

```
self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)
```

This will dismiss Safari.